# Vertical Tabs in Panel Pages

Tags: panels, forms

I am trying to have three forms available to the public on my site and would love to have them configured in in the vertical tabs layout. Initially I was going to have them available through node/add/form but I have since decided I would rather have them in a panel page to lose that path of node/add. Now that I have the forms in the panel page they no longer have the vertical tab/fieldset layout. How would I go about putting the forms back in that tabbed layout while staying in a panel page?

Comment: Did you find a solution on this?I have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like someone has fixed this in style!
https://drupal.org/project/node_vertical_tab_elements

Haven't tried it myself, but it looks made exactly to fix this issue.